# How to add Custom Role for “Virtual Machine operator” to set Auto-shut down

Tags: azure

I want to create a custom role in Azure to allow "Virtual machine operator" to set Auto-shutdown time.

I tried creating a custom role using JSON but don't know which is the action for "Auto-shutdown"

```
 {
  "Name": "Virtual Machine Operator 2",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Can deallocate, start  and restart virtual machines.",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.Compute/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action",
"Microsoft.Compute/Auto-shutdown/*"
  ],
  "NotActions": [


  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/8c18015f-f6be-403d-905d-5cdfcb1f1c1d"
  ]
}
```

The line in above JSON is incorrect
"Microsoft.Compute/Auto-shutdown/*"

Comment: Look at these links: [MS Documentation: Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management), [Automatic Shutdown Settings in Azure VMs](https://www.petri.com/automatic-shutdown-settings-azure-vms) and [Start and Stop Windows Azure VMs According to Time Schedule](http://azurecorner.com/start-stop-windows-azure-vms-according-time-schedule/).  The latter is from 2014, but the first two should be up-to-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable the `Auto-shutdown` for the VM, the Azure will create a resource whose resource type is `Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules` in the resource group the VM located. You could check it in the resource group(choose the `Show hidden types` option).

[image]

So if you want to set the `Auto-shutdown` time, you will need the `Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules/*` permission(maybe the `Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules/write` is the minimum permission, I have just test `Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules/*`).

Meanwhile, when we set the `Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules`, we also actually set the VM(the resource is linked to the VM scope), so we also need the `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write` permission, otherwise you will get an error.

**In conclusion**, the custom role `.json` file should be like below.

```
 {
  "Name": "Virtual Machine Operator 2",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Can deallocate, start  and restart virtual machines.",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.Compute/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action",
    "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules/*",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write"
  ],
  "NotActions": [


  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ]
}
```

---

**Besides**, I test the custom role to set the `Auto-shutdown` setting with a service principal context in the powershell, it works fine on my side, you could also have a try.

```
$resourcegroup = "<resource group name>"
$vm = "<VM Name>"
$shutdown_time = "1900"
$shutdown_timezone = "China Standard Time"

$properties = @{
    "status" = "Enabled";
    "taskType" = "ComputeVmShutdownTask";
    "dailyRecurrence" = @{"time" = $shutdown_time };
    "timeZoneId" = $shutdown_timezone;
    "notificationSettings" = @{
        "status" = "Disabled";
        "timeInMinutes" = 30
    }
    "targetResourceId" = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Id
}

Set-AzResource -ResourceId ("/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{2}" -f (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id, $resourcegroup, $vm) -Properties $properties -Force
```

Comment: I confirm that @Joy Wang, I tried a custom role with all the permissions for VM under"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/" and it still allow to save the Auto-Shutdown changes. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write" gives user to make changes in VM, including VM size change. What if only giving them right to change Auto-Shutdown time only. How can it be done??

Comment: @JitendraGupta I don't think there is such an operation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftcompute